# Validate CSV by Converting it into XML and validating with xsd and get he row number of CSV for error

Tags: xml, csv

I have a CSV file for upload. I am converting that file to XML so that it can validated against xsd file. I am validating the XML file with the xsd file using xmlReader.

I want to know if there is a way I can get the line number or row number of CSV where the validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Number the lines before you parse the CSV file:

```
$ head /etc/passwd | nl -s:
 1:root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
 2:daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
 3:bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
 4:sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
 5:sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
 6:games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
 7:man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
 8:lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
 9:mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
10:news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
```

Replace the colon with the character that matches your CSV input format.

Comment: i am converting the CSV file to XML by using dataset.
How to number the lines in this case